# Waiting for table level lock innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking, mysql-8.0

We had a table which in empty. But due to some business logic the table gets queried anyway. This was working fine but today suddenly all the queries on that table were taking a lot of time due to `Waiting for table level lock` .
Checked the process list to see any alter/update but apart from reads there were no other query apart from reads on that entire DB .

(AWS RDS)MySQL Version 8.0.21

MySQL Engine - InnoDb

Table Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `empty_table` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `area_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `test_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `temp_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ghost_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `cutoff` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `cutoff_day` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_on` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_by_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `empty_table_id_uindex` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `empty_table_pk` (`area_id`,`test_id`,`temp_id`,`ghost_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `empty_table_area_id_test_id_temp_id_ghost_id_uindex` (`area_id`,`test_id`,`temp_id`,`ghost_id`),
  KEY `empty_table_path_ghost_id_fk` (`ghost_id`),
  KEY `empty_table_area_id_test_id_temp_id_ghost_id_index` (`area_id`,`test_id`,`temp_id`,`ghost_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `empty_table_path_ghost_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`ghost_id`) REFERENCES `ghost` (`ghost_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

SQL Query - `Select * from empty_table where area_id=1 AND test_id=1 AND temp_id=1 AND ghost_id=1`

The writes are less in this DB. ( Worst case 30 Inserts/updates statements in 1 day)

Comment: Eh?  The table is empty, yet an Alter or Update is not finishing "instantly"??

Comment: You have 4 Unique indexes, two of the are redundant.  The one `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key.  A `UNIQUE` key is a key.

Comment: @RickJames There was no alter on that table any time(Thats what i confirmed with the Show process list) . Last alter happened like 12 months back.  
How would having multiple primary key cause `Waiting for table level lock` . ? Also We are using INNODB engine so there should not be a case for table level lock.

Comment: You can query `select p.* from performance_schema.metadata_locks l
join performance_schema.threads t on l.owner_thread_id = t.thread_id
join performance_schema.processlist p on t.processlist_id = p.id
where l.object_name='t' and l.lock_status='GRANTED'` to see which process holds the table lock.

Comment: @BillKarwin then the process list would have shown waiting for metadata lock and not waiting for table level lock

Comment: I cannot reproduce that processlist state with an InnoDB table. I can reproduce it with a MyISAM table. I suggest you double-check that your table is not MyISAM.

Comment: @BillKarwin checked that , it's not MyISAM.

Comment: Okay I can't explain it. Note that some session may hold a lock on that table with `LOCK TABLES` or with a transactional locking statement, even though if you view `SHOW PROCESSLIST` now, the session is not running a query. I don't have any suggestions. Good luck!

Comment: @BillKarwin the table is empty and has never been written to. There is no transaction that locks this specific table.  Looks like a bug in MySQL , will try to reproduce it .

Comment: Since it is Amazon RDS, they might have done something nonstandard. They have  made changes to code and configuration, without publicly documenting what they did. You should contact your AWS support channel for help resolving this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will do that